# Matchphrase Query Elastic Search not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have document containing field category and title and some other fields stored in elastic db.
I need to search a phrase in title field of document but I do not get the document.
below is c# code I used

sd = new SearchDescriptor();

```
sd.Query(q =>  
 q.MatchPhrase(m => m
  .Field(p => p.title)
  .Query("Test Article in Credit")  
  ));
```

There is a document having title(fieldname) as "Test Article in Credit" but I do get 2 document but actually there are 5.

If I use match phrase in different field it does work but in above field it is not giving me desired result.

I took out the raw json from above nest query by serializing to memory stream.
The raw json looked as below

```
{  
  "query": {  
  "match_phrase": {  
      "title": {  
        "query": "Test Article in Credit"  
       }  
    }  
  }  
}
```

If I use the above raw query it gave me 5 documents but if i do nest query it gives me 2 documents.

I am not sure what i am missing.

Comment: Do you have any special mappings or analyzer settings on this index? Maybe you could post them, if so. Other than that, have you tried - just to test - if it works with a direct post request to ES (could identify if it's an error in your code). Or if it works if you set the fieldName of the title as string (hardcoded to test).

Comment: It used default standard analyzer and I tried posting query directly it worked which means there is some problem in my nest query. Thanks

Comment: I do not know why nest query does not work as raw jason part of it

Comment: @Ans you can log out the request that NEST sends and compare? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/logging.html

Comment: Thanks Russ, I got it the request body seems to fine for both but the one which gave all documents was searching all indices and other one on specific index.